# Passing a Gravity Forms Entry Value (PHP and AJAX) to a Google Chart (JS)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

So here's a brainteaser. I have a Gravity Form (using AJAX) that has several radio buttons with different values assigned to them. When the user selects one of the 5 button options for a question, it assigns a value to that answer between 2 and 5.

I'm looking to pass that data to a Google Pie chart, and have several answers populate that chart. I have the two pieces of the puzzle set up, all I need to do is get that information from the Form to my JS file as a variable.

Before you can say "repost", let me explain my method: I've already looked into a lot of posts here about passing PHP variables to JS. Here's my setup:

In my functions.php file, I declare a set of 7 variables that correspond to my 7 questions. Let's make this simple and use just one for an example:

```
$scoreOne;
```

Then, below (in a function), I call that variable globally and assign it the value of the form input.

```
$GLOBALS['scoreOne'] = rgpost('input_18');
```

Below that (and outside of the preceding function), I close my php tags, and encode the variable in JSON like so:

```
<script>
    var scoreOneJson = <?php echo json_encode("$scoreOne", JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
</script>
```

Moving on to my .js file: I'm using Google's Pie Chart visualization (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)

The chart itself works fine if I put in straight numbers as variables. However we want to call that variable that we just encoded:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Category', 'Score'],
['Score One', scoreOneJson],
['Score Two', 2],
['Score Three', 3],
]);
```

Yet this doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the following plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/gf-charts-reports/ instead of Google Charts, so as to output chartsjs charts from gravity forms datas.